# How can I stop (doom-)emacs from auto completing the colon of a function definition in python?

Tags: python, emacs

I currently have the problem that whenever I am writing the beginning of a function definition:

```py
def function():
```

When I type the `(` the rest (`):`) is auto completed. I do not mind the auto completion but annoying is that unlike the `)` I am not able to overwrite the completed `:`.
I experienced either the same or a similar problem a while back with spacemacs. I think it might be a problem with `python-mode` but I have not been able to make out what exactly is causing the problem or how to fix it.

EDIT: After knowing the cause was `smartparens` I tried `electric-pair` but wasn't too happy about some behaviour of it. My final solution is to disable this behaviour in smartparens by adding the following to my config.

```lisp
(setq sp-python-insert-colon-in-function-definitions nil)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because of `smartparens`, see https://github.com/hlissner/doom-emacs/issues/5151